# I am getting this message from my Samsung ML-1666 printer "end of life, replace with new toner cartridges - 1043S(MLT-D1043S)"

Tags: printer, laser-printer

I am getting this message from my Samsung ML-1666 printer "end of life, replace with new toner cartridges - 1043S(MLT-D1043S)".

Also, when the toner is attached, a red light beneath the printer's start button blinks. That means, the toner has some problem.

I do not want to buy new cartridge. I want to refill. But I think the printer's print-counter should be reset.

What to do?

Comment: Is the toner empty or …?

Comment: No toner is not fully empty. It was printing. Suddenly stopped and giving the message.

Comment: Since it is a low end model, I bet you just have to replace the cartridge, use the chat function on this page....http://www.samsung.com/in/support/model/ML-1666/XIP

Comment: Please put the necessary information from that link into your question.

Comment: Have you ever tried to resolve the problem by replacing the drum of the cartridge.

Comment: I am 100% confirm that the drum is OK.

Answer (score 1):

The site I use quite often, [tonertopup](http://www.tonertopup.co.uk/productCatalog.asp?Manufacturer=347&Model=ML-1666&Engine=Samsung%20ML-1665%20HY%20All-In-One) suggests you need a reset chip in addition to the toner.

Comment: How can I reset the chip at my home?

Comment: I imagine it's not impossible but probably not worth the cost of buying whatever is required to do this at home vs cost of reset chip.

Comment: You had a cheap refill. Every refill shop should reset your cartridges as well as filling them up.

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest you to refill toner cartridge because toner powder is very fine and you do not want to breath in the powder toner. When the toner cartridge runs out or empty the printer will not print more documents or prints will be very faint. You may be able to print a few pages left to remove the toner cartridge and shaking the toner cartridge in a horizontal position a few times and then put it back into your printer. This will give you a little chance to print a few more pages and give you time to buy a new toner cartridge for your printer. A cheaper alternative is to buy remanufactured toner cartridge for your modelprinter.